# Need help in developing a custom WebDav client using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, webdav

I am developing an open source application which should mount webdav share to local drive letter just like NETDRIVE and WEBDRIVE using node.js and electron-js, so in my application at present I am downloading all files from webdav share which takes a lot of time and not reliable for heavy data. Is there any other approach so that whenever user access a file, only that particular file should be fetched from webdav share, I’ve tried to display files meta data(dummy) structure in directory and kept that directory under file-watcher. So that when user tries to open a file then watcher should capture file open event to get which file was user trying to access, so that in background of application a service will triggered to fetch that particular file using file-path as reference, but none of them are unable to capture file open event. Is there any other approach to do so, correct me if I am in wrong direction.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I think you want virtual file-system and recommend Dokan library.
Dokan is the start point of Windows virtual file-system application.

- Open Source : Dokan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dokan_Library)
- Commercial: EldoS CBFS (https://www.eldos.com/cbfs)

Google, Naver use Dokan and NetDrive, RaiDrive(mine) use CBFS.